# How do I make images on a webpage fit inside a max width WITHOUT compromising smaller images?

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a blog set-up for my website. Imagine there is a limited space for an article, and I want to define an area for there to be an image at the top of the articles that can never exceed a maximum width. What I have so far is basic CSS styling to define the `max-width`, etc. What I want to know is how can I control it so that smaller images do not get affected?

I.e. So if I have a space of 700px, images larger than 700px will get sized down but images smaller than 700px will stay the same and maybe be centered or whatever I wanted.

I looked around but couldn't find a way to word this that would yield results. If this can't be done through CSS, I also have PHP to work with if necessary.

Thanks for reading and any help!

Comment: v__v Okay, so every post I found said to have "width: 100%" for some reason along with defining a max-width, so that's why it didn't work for me. Turns out if you just define a max-width it works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Using pure CSS you can do this:

```
.post img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Note: this is IE8+, and other latest browsers. See: http://caniuse.com/#search=max-width

Comment: What does the auto do in the first two exactly?

Comment: Oh okay. I put it in a comment above, but for some reason all the posts I could find on this said to have the width at 100% for some reason :/ Idk why that is, maybe they were just interested in maximizing space or something. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: If you have FireFox, download/install FireBug extension. If you have Chrome, use Chrome inspector.

Answer (score 0):

U may try % instead of px.
This will automatically resizes the image.
try to use % or am as it displays the same result on all screen sizes.

U can also use % above 100 this will enlarge the image size .

Regards !